# how to render multiple 'vis-react' component in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I want to render multiple topology using `vis-react` component using react js.
Any suggestions how to proceed?
I am using ES6

Comment: 'vis-react' is just as the same as other react component which you can you can use them in the same page and set unique key for each of them, can you specify your question? in which part do you have a question? As you better know you can find many example in this site 'https://uber.github.io/react-vis/examples/showcases/plots'

Comment: i want to render multiple topology graph using 'vis-react'. so how to loop to display those component one by one.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an array that you want to fill chart data with its items you can do this

```
    render() {
        let counter = 0;
        const items= this.props.data.map(item => {
            return (
                <XYPlot
                    width={300}
                    height={300}>
                    <HorizontalGridLines />
                    <LineSeries data={[item.data]}/>
                    <XAxis />
                    <YAxis />
                </XYPlot>
                )
            })

            return (
                <div>
                    {items}
                </div>
            )
        }
```

if you have some other sources you have to set it manually like this :

```
  render() {
      return (
          <XYPlot key='1'
              width={300}
              height={300}>
                  <HorizontalGridLines />
                  <LineSeries
                      data={[
                        {x: 1, y: 10},
                        {x: 2, y: 5},
                        {x: 3, y: 15}
                      ]}/>
                  <XAxis />
                  <YAxis />
            </XYPlot>

            <XYPlot key = '2'
               width={300}
               height={300}>
               <HorizontalGridLines />
               <LineSeries
                   data={[
                      {x: 1, y: 10},
                      {x: 2, y: 5},
                      {x: 3, y: 15}
                   ]}/>
              <XAxis />
              <YAxis />
            </XYPlot>
            )
        }
```

Comment: Actually I want to create graph topology where one network is connected to multple VM. i have component graph which needs ex: Graph{}

Comment: graph[ node:[{Vmname:1,resource:"name1" } , {Vmname:2,resource:"name2" } , {Vmname:3,resource:"name3" }] ,  edges: [ {from : 1, to : 2 } , {from : 1, to : 3 } , {from : 1, to : 4 } ]  }

Comment: when is the graph loaded? you want to use ajax call to fill it or it send as a prop to your component?